# Timer/Stopwatch for Windows that looks nice and is "always on top" or in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, time-management

I want a simple task timer or stopwatch that I can pause and restart.  I would like it to look decent, minimal and be able to run "always on top" of other windows.  Ideally, no chrome (windows close button, minimize, border, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm far far from in the future then when this post was posted but if people are still interested, I'd go with the default clock app that you get in Windows 10/11.

There's an option to go "always on top" with the following button.

[image]

This is what it looks like when on top.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Topic looks a little bit outdated but [XNote Stopwatch](http://www.xnotestopwatch.com) is ideally what the op was looking for. Hope that helps anyone else.

[image: XNote Stopwatch "always on top"]

Answer (score 5):

[Countdown Timer](http://getwinpcsoft.com/Free-Countdown-Timer-1903407/) by Comfort Software Group works for me.

It has both **timer and stopwatch** functions, **pause/reset** options, can always **stay on top** of other windows.

I'm not sure what 'look decent' means for you - its **UI is simple**, with no nice design and whatnot, but it **can be minimized** to show only time left/passed.

Also, it's a **free** download, if that helps. :)

Comment: Not bad. Interestingly, their page had an ad to another one that looks promising: https://hotalarmclock.com/

Comment: As of version 5.1, if you dismiss a floating window, you can't use it again. You have to delete the timer and re-create it.

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous answers suited my needs. XNote has the obnoxious millisecond timer with no way to change precision in the free version. I have found an open-source alternative [LYZ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lyz/files/LYZ_stopwatch_timer/Release) which is riddled with fewer bs and is more aesthetically pleasing.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to name the timer so that >1 timers running at the same time can be differentiated?

Answer (score 2):

really like [r timer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/r-timer/9nbdcpv73wlb?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) for the minimal interface
[image: rtimer Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome Denny!  Please add a screenshot, and indicate how it meets the OP's requirements.  Also, if you can include a link to the developer's site, that will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/universal-clock-utility-overlay-uwp-clock-timer-and-countdown/9pm1lsf9fw1h?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)]
[image]
or [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/visual-timers/9wzdncrdfcjp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
[image]
from the Windows app store?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I work for PresentationTools, the author of this software.**

CueTimer can also do this, with the "preview" window that can be placed anywhere on the screen and will always stay on top of other windows.

We will soon release a new version where this window can have transparent background.

https://presentationtools.com/cuetimer

Comment: This looks like a solid product, but I would expect a one-time purchase. A subscription fee for this type of tool is a no-go.